# How to send large files using Hamachi

Tags: file-sharing, hamachi

I want to download some big files from my friend. We tried torrent but there is some port forwarding problem with his router.

We already enjoy games with Hamachi, how can he share big files in 'resumable' way so that i can download them easily in parts?

Answer (score 2):

One of you sets up an ftp server (Filezilla Server portable comes to mind) and then you can transer those files over the hamachi connection.

Comment: Does it support resumable downloads?

Comment: I would choose the SFTP protocol before I chose FTP as my method of file transfer.

Comment: @LifeH2O yes, it does

Comment: @brandon927 traffic is already encrypted due to the hamachi connection, so I do not see the point here, but you can do this (FTPS) with Filezilla Server if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

well, hamachi is a VPN, so running a web server, and a resumable downloader of some sort might work, or any error tolerant method you'd use to transfer files over a LAN would work.

If you weren't looking for a hamachi based option, though some form of cloud file transfer service and clever zipping might work better, IMO

Comment: Thanks, i think web server and a download manager will work. Can you please name some other tools that i should use in order to avoid that port forwarding issue?

Comment: as long as you use the hamachi IP address, pretty much anything would work. stuff you'd usually use on the lan would not work too well with a high latency connection tho

Answer (score 1):

You could also try https://wetransfer.com. It's a quite good service, flash based and actually no problems with transfering large files (tested with 1,4 GB ISO Images).

Comment: all i need is a resumable file transfer over vpn without messing with port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

2 services that I frequently use are [dushare](http://www.dushare.com/#) and [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/) for sharing rather large files. Another solution may be to both install and share a folder between yourselves with [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTM0MDgwNDQ5?src=global0). Lifehacker.com covers a great deal on the uses of dropbox, and [this](http://lifehacker.com/5707510/use-dropbox-to-transfer-over-a-large-queue-of-files) particular situation is one of them. Along with the transferring of large files, I would try to accomplish a high level of compression in order to save bandwidth. [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and [Peazip](http://www.peazip.org/index.html) are some excellent open source archiving and file managers to do the job.

Comment: dushare and ge.tt are browser based, i think it will be impossible to transfer huge file in parts. Dropbox will first upload and then download. Using direct connection hamachi is a better idea.

Comment: actually, Dropbox will do direct sync in a lan

Comment: @The Journeyman geek What? Really? But dropbox connects to internet abd upload everything there.

Comment: like @The Journeyman said, If you have LAN sync enabled, and you're both on the Hamachi VPN with a folder shared, It'll sync directly back and forth